# play! deployment: netty good enough for 5k unique visitors?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, netty

I'm trying to figure out the deployment process when it comes up to play! apps.

I've read some resources about that topic, some sources say that netty is good enough for production apps on the other hand a friend of mine told me that it's not good for production apps.

I'm talking about let's say 5k unique users a day, can this be handled with the out of the box solution from the play framework?

Comment: Those people how down voted my question clearly haven't read the question. This is not opinion based either it can handle 5k users or it can't. That's how simple it is.

Comment: Not that I downvoted, but "a friend of mine told me" questions are bound to be closed. A Google search would have answered your question easily. And fwiw, 5k users a day can be handled by any modern framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netty is one of the fastest IO library out there. It can handle 200k responses / second on EC2 regarding [this benchmark](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r9&hw=ec2&test=plaintext). Netty is the library that power Finagle, Twitter's open source RPC system.

It definitely can handle 5k user per day.

Answer (score 0):

What can I say... Play with netty is able to respond to thousands unique requests per **second** so probably your friend mismatched terms...